# The best way of running a command in the background and logging out (Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have a website in a folder like /home/www/html/domain-name.com, and it is quite large, with a lot of picture files, like jpg, gif. I would like to find the best possible way of logging in to the system over ssh, and getting a tar.gz file with this folder, which I could later download over ftp. I would like to add it a higher nice value too, if this could make it faster, as I am not sure whether the command will complete overnight.

So far, I have figured out something like this:

```
$ nohup nice -10 tar –zcvf domain-name.com-24-03-2016.tar.gz domain-name.com &
```

...and then log out. Then I would like to log in in the morning, after like 9-10 hours, and download this file over ftp. The folder is around 500GB lets say.

a) Will this command work as is, or do I need to run in differently, with some sort of pipes lets sa? 
b) Is there a better way of achieving something like this? 
c) Is -10 the right value for the nice command? (It is a dedicated server, with only 2 websites and overall traffic of around 400 people per day, and nothing else).

So pretty much I am looking for the best and the fastest way of achieving something like this. If I could speed it up even more, this would be even better, so I would not have to leave the pc running overnight.

Comment: If I use nohup at the beginning, I don't have to put it in the background with the & at the end I guess, but I am not sure.

Comment: well if you are doing it every day, you can just schedule a task in cron to run it, and it will be waiting for you in the morning.  or you can run it under something like screen or tmux so you detach from it and then connect back later.

Comment: but also if you want it to run faster don't run it under nice :), but that might have an effect on server performance.

Comment: @Doon, Thanks. I wont be doing it every day for now. Something like once per month should do it. But still, looking for the best and the fastest way.

Comment: Why don't you create a `cron` job which daily makes this compression ? Then you can download the file whenever you want through a simple `scp` command.

Answer (score 1):

I would just build a simple backup script

```
#!/bin/sh 
cd /path/to/someplace 
/path/to/tar –zcvf /location/of/backup/domain-name.com-$(date +%F).tar.gz domain-name.com
echo "backup complete" | /path/to/mail -s "backup complete" your@email.addresss
```

and then run it out on crontab on first of month.

```
0 0 1 * * backup.sh
```